# How to host AngularJs application over IIS

Tags: angularjs, iis, hosting

I am new to AngularJs application and using Gulp to compile application. When I compile my application, it creates a directory with name `app` in my solution. I have the following folders in `app`.

[image]

This is deployable code and I want to deploy it on local IIS.
What is needed to tell IIS to start from or is configuration file needed there.

I set application pool like this

[image]

Any help please despite this awkward illustration.

Answer (score 1):

This is not hard, as long as you are in control of your `web.config`. Basically what you need to do is a 301 Permanent Redirect.

This is how to do a mod_rewrite in IIS, under your `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="directToSubFolder" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Note that the `url` in the `action` tag value should be whatever that suits your needs. I am assuming your default landing is an `index.html`

So with this, you can do your development as usual, once you want to deploy, you can run Gulp to build everything into `app` folder, and voila, you are done!

Comment: No, this is not working. `rewrite` is underlined. I don't understand it. All the settings are in app.js, how can I trigger it at first.

Comment: are you running node.js server code in the project? if yes, then it's a different story.

Comment: Yes, I am using node.js. I don't know how IIS will initiate to pick files.

Comment: then the question should be how to deploy a nodejs application in IIS server and not an angular specific question.